# Amide fragmentation of salicylamide

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I want to ask a question about the fragmentation of the $\ce{M_17}$ peak of Salicyclamide to a phenolic fragment.

I was reading the following paper giving a profile about [salicyclamide](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231350583_33-_Analytical_Profile_of_Salicylamide).

I want to determine a mechanism that gives the following product from the fragmentation scheme:

[image: Overall fragmentation scheme based from the mass spec analysis]

I am however, unable to so far produce a mechanism that shows the scheme above.

The figure below shows the closest attempt I have made so far.

[image: Attempt at a reasonable mechanism]

I feel my attempt is incorrect since there is a net charge change.

What mistake am I making that can rectify my result and provide a reasonable suggestion for the mechanism involved?

**I don't understand how this question can be voted for closure as it is "not relevant to chemistry".** This is a clear phenomena given in a research paper and I wanted to discuss the mechanism(s) behind such findings that have been observed in the paper - as noted in the help centre under *Questions relating to observed chemical phenomena*.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that for an $\ce{m/z = 92}$ you would need a $\ce{C6H4}$ ring with only an oxygen group attached. If a positive charge is present, this implies that there is a radical at position 2 ortho to the $\ce{C=O}$.

I revised my own mechanism below to suggest one possible route:

[image: Possible mechanism.]